# Is $SL(2,3)$ have only $4$ normal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, linear-groups

I'm look at the special linear group and have a question: Is that $SL(2,3)$ have only $4$ normal subgroup? and how to prove the part "only"?

I can see that the two triviral subgroups, the centre and there is a 2-Sylow subgroup are all normal in $SL(2,3)$, but are there another normal?

Thank for anwser my question.

Comment: Yes that's right. Apart from that there are four subgroups of order $3$, which are conjugate and so not normal, and their direct products with the centre, similar. There are also three cyclic subgroups of order $4$ which are conjugate (by an element of order 3) and therefore not normal. There are no other subgroups.

Comment: why you know the number subgroups of order $3$? Is there some prove or we have to compute it directly?

Comment: It follow from Sylow's theorem. Or you can calculate it from the fact that the upper unitriangular matrices form a Sylow $3$-subgroup and its normalizer consists of the upper triangular matrices. That's the same in ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ for any $q$.

Comment: Ah, i just check the Sylow's theorem and understand it, but why there are no other subgroups? Is there any prove that $SL(2,3)$ have only 15 subgroup? The 3rd Sylow's theorem just show the number of $2$ and $3$-sylow subgroup.

Comment: The subgroups of order $6$ are just the normalizers of the Sylow $3$-subgroups - that also follows directly from Sylow's theorem. There are no subgroups of order $12$. You should try and prove that yourself.